# Blender 2.8 OpenGL requirements and Render Farms

Tags: rendering, opengl

I am currently theory crafting with my IT team about getting Blender installed on our render farm.  However the render blades we have do not have GPUs currently installed.  I was wondering if this would be an issue with 2.8 due to the Hardware requirement?

These blades already handle Vray stand alone which we are eventually going to utilize once the 3D program we are using gives us a released build with Vray.  But in the mean time I am trying to utilize blender for Deadline based farm rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to render from command line without the graphical user interface without trouble. You can find more info on that [in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workflows/command_line.html)

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.8 will work on nodes without GPU (as proof, we have 2.8 rendering on CPU on RenderStreet). The requirement to use OpenGL comes from the new rendering engine added in 2.8, Eevee. If you don't use it, then 2.8 will work the same as the previous version.